# How to add labels to a stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to add numerical values to the middle of each stack in the stacked bar graph (code below). Most of the examples I am finding are orientated towards information in one column and whenever I try to modify it, I run into errors about length requirements.

```
DA <- data.frame(
  Imp=c("2015","2019"),
  "mismatch"=c(220,209),
  "match"=c(3465,3347),
  "NA"=c(501,630),
  check.names = FALSE)

DA %>%
  pivot_longer(-Imp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Imp, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name=" ", values=c("aquamarine4", "orange", "coral")) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y=4300, label="Stretch it"), vjust=-1) +
  labs(y="Count", x="Imputed Genotypes") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="white", width = 1)
```

Comment: A continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408301/how-to-make-a-stacked-plot-in-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

DA <- data.frame(
  Imp=c("2015","2019"),
  "mismatch"=c(220,209),
  "match"=c(3465,3347),
  "NA"=c(501,630),
  check.names = FALSE)

DA %>%
  pivot_longer(-Imp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Imp, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(color = "white", lwd = 1,
           position = "stack", width = 0.75) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=c("aquamarine4", "orange", "coral")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0, 4200)) +
  labs(y="Imputed Genotypes (Count)") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), color = "white", size = 5, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_light(base_size = 18) +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>